# Convert PHP Date substring "month" date format to uppercase

Tags: php, substr

I have a PHP code that outputs the alphabetical value of the month of the year and then I substring the value to show only the last letter i.e:`<?php echo substr(date("M"),2);?>`

It works well but the only problem is the result is in lowercase. The result i get is "g" in the case of "Aug" instead of "G".

Can someone help with a code snippet to do this? I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance,
Ralph.

Comment: So `php uppercase`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you going to do for `Mar` and `Apr`? They are both `r`...

Comment: Hmm, this is quite interesting Chin, please how can we overcome this problem?

Comment: Problem solved. I just had to reverse the values in the array to get the code working. Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using strtoupper the output will be as you expected:

```
<?php echo strtoupper(substr(date("M"),2));?>
```

Comment: Great work @Felipe! It worked like abracadabra! nifty and quick, just the way I love them. Good work!